# Where to position this vector?

Tags: c++

I have constructed a minimal "working" example - If you comment out all the references to items_ then the code compiles and executes fine. I have to populate a vector from inside a friend method and then access those contents from another object from a different class.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <set>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

namespace autodiff {
namespace base {
class var {
public:
    friend var operator+(const var& l, const var& r) {
        var result;
        // need to populate items_ here!
        items_.push_back(result.left_);
        items_.push_back(result.right_);
        // ... 
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<var> left_;
    std::shared_ptr<var> right_;
};

static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<var>> items_;

class expression {
public:
    expression(var v) {
        // need items here!!
        for (const auto& i : items_) {
            // need to do stuff with items_ in here...
        }
    };

}  // namespace base
}  // namespace autodiff
```

I have tried moving the static vector to various locations but the same error keeps appearing:

```
‘items_’ was not declared in this scope
```

This is obvious to me. Putting it above var or below it doesn't make sense. However, I can't think of a workaround. I have tried to put it in a namespace.

Comment: Option 1: define `items_` before all these classes, write `class var;` (just that line) before it. Option 2: move method definitions down below, after `items_`. Option 3: make `items_` a static field. Option 4: get rid of `items_` altogether; I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I suspect you don't really need to store a copy of each element happening in an expression, an expression can own all of its children.

Comment: This code smells wrong. What is it this code is supposed to be doing? It looks like you are mixing up the ideas between Parsing and an AST and an Environment Table.

Comment: I too wonder what it should do, but I think 'l' and 'r' should be used in the 'operator+'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 1: define `items_` before all these classes, write `class var;` (just that line) before it. Option 2: move method definitions down below, after `items_`. Option 3: make `items_` a static field. Option 4: get rid of `items_` altogether; I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I suspect you don't really need to store a copy of each element happening in an expression, an expression can own all of its children.

– answer by [yeputons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767632/yeputons)